# Detached Garage Subpanel to House Main Panel

Tags: electrical-panel

Can I connect a 60 amp (8 space) subpanel from a detached garage to the house main panel that is also 60 amp? The house panel has 4 spaces available unused.

The subpanel underground wiring is 4 wires (2 hot, 1 neutral, 1 ground) within 1 1/2" schedule 80 PVC and buried 30" below grade with a distance of 40 feet from detached garage to the house.

The house is small (775 SF).
The detached garage is 24'x24' (576 SF) two car size.

Comment: What make and model are the panels in question? I take it the house doesn't have any large electric appliances for that matter? (i.e. an electric water heater, electric range, electric clothes dryer, electric heat, or an air conditioner)

Comment: What is the size of the (evidently already in place) subpanel wiring?

Comment: How did you determine the house panel was rated only 60A? Are you sure it isn't a split bus panel with one of 6 or less mains being a 60A feeding a smaller section of the panel? A picture of the panel would be great.

Comment: We generally recommend *much* larger panels than an 8-space. You'll max out those 8 spaces long before you use all 60A. Spaces are cheap, running out of spaces is frustrating and so easily avoided.

Comment: Sure you can connect a 60 amp panel to a 60 amp panel. Infact you can connect a 200 amp panel to that 60 amp panel. More information would be needed to say if this is a wise decision or not.